# TSQL - Creating a Trigger to auto-move new db files to correct location?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Lets say I'm running a SQL Server instance with many new Databases added per week.

For the sake of consistency, I want all my database data files in `Z:\Data` and all my log files in `Z:\Log`. 9 out of 10 the files are installed in the right location but 1/10 times, they are not (either due to uncontrollable installation defaults or human error).

What I'd like to do is detect when a new database file is added, or if it is moved, by triggering on Insert or Update against `sys.master_files` view, which I understand is not possible (because it is a view), and\or can only be achieved by using [INSTEAD OF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx) and scheduling a [SQL Agent Job](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c57866e3-73bc-455f-b038-76f90220d730/need-trigger-on-system-view-to-update-on-user-database?forum=transactsql).

I'd like to try to get the filenames from a trigger, if possible, and avoid using the agent. **Is there an actual table with filepaths that I can trigger on?**

In addition, these instances are in constant production, and due to fear of production data loss, the script I'm using to move the files will only queue them for move the next time the sql service is restarted, which means I'd still have to manually schedule a service restart. This isn't terrible - I'd prefer to guarantee no data loss just to move the files, but is there a better way? Can I in any way trigger\capture the database file's location on create\attach\move before the database comes online?

```
--Example
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'Z:\Data\Tempdb.mdf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'Z:\Log\Tempdb.ldf');
GO
--No trigger on sys.master_files
--Requires SQL Service restart :-(
```

Comment: You probably need a DDL trigger on `Alter_database`

Comment: Thank you very much, @MartinSmith . I believe you are correct. I've found the following link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.105).aspx which confirms your comment - allowing me to trigger on CREATE, ALTER, and DROP statements. I will try to put an example together as an answer after I've had a chance to test and confirm, unless you have a quick example you'd like to post as an answer first :-)